# applying image decoration (border) in Python (programmatically)

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am looking for a way to create a border in python.Is there any library in Python which we can import to create a border.

Note that I do not want to use any image masks to create this effect (e.g. I don't want to use any image editing package like GIMP to create a border image mask) .

Here is what I am looking for:

```
import fooImageBorders 
import Image 

foo = Image.open("someImage.jpg")
foo2 = fooImageBorders.bevel(foo, color = black)
```

...I can write my own methods to add borders .. but if there is already something like this out there with a comprehensive set of border options, I would like to make use of it.

I looked at PIL documentation and couldn't find a way to do this. I have windows xp and there doesn't seem to be a way to install PythonMagick either for Python 2.6 if you don't have cygwin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the [ImageOps](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageops.htm) module within the PIL.

```
import Image
import ImageOps

x = Image.open('test.png')
y = ImageOps.expand(x,border=5,fill='red')
y.save('test2.png')
```

Comment: yes, this addresses one border type (plain border) . For bevel edges etc it seems I need to write my own functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [PythonMagick module](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/). the documentation for this module is [here (Magic ++ documentation)](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#Image%20Manipulation%20Methods)

Example: To add a red 2 pixel border to an image, you need following code.

```
from PythonMagick import Image
i = Image('example.jpg') # reades image and creates an image instance
i.borderColor("#ff0000") # sets border paint color to red
i.border("2x2") # paints a 2 pixel border
i.write("out.jpg")
# writes the image to a file
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am on Windows and they don't have an installer for Python2.6 onwards. http://wiki.wxpython.org/PythonMagick. (Although it can be installed from sources ... it is unix style installation ...I don't have cygwin and just want to use regular windows env)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. I think would be faster to do it yourself.

Comment: This is definitely good option provided PythonMagick can be easily installed on Windows

Answer (score 1):

```
foo2 = foo.copy()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(foo2)
for i in range(width):
    draw.rectangle([i, i, foo2.size[0]-i-1, foo2.size[1]-i-1], outline = color)
```

`foo2` will have a `width`-pixel border of `color`.

If you want different colored borders on each side, you can replace `.rectangle` with repeated `.line` calls.

If you want the border not to cover any part of the existing image, use this instead of `foo.copy()`.

```
foo2 = Image.new(foo.mode, (foo.size[0] + 2*width, foo.size[1] + 2*width))
foo2.paste(foo, (width, width))
```

Comment: yeap, this works too (but I wanted to know if there is a library that can support a comprehensive set of borders). Thank you!